# comparing c++ char struct to an ASCII value yields an error

Tags: c++, arrays

```
if (sale->taxStatus[i] = "y")  // line 44
```

yields error:

`y.cpp:44:12: error: request for member taxStatus in sale, which is of non-class type Sale*`

My struct:

```
struct Sale {
    int quantity[MAX_SALES];
    float unitPrice[MAX_SALES];
    char taxStatus[MAX_SALES]; // MAX_SALES = 10
};
```

the full function:

```
void total(struct Sale sale[], int sales) {

    int i = 0;
    float subTotal, hst, total = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < sales; i++) {
        subTotal = subTotal + (sale->quantity[i] * sale->unitPrice[i]);
        if (sale->taxStatus[i] = "y")
        {
            hst = hst + ((sale->quantity[i] * sale->unitPrice[i]) * 0.13);
        }
    }

    cout << "\n" << "Subtotal  : " << subTotal << endl;   
    cout << "HST (13%) : " << hst;   
}
```

Comment: Use `==` for equality, `=` for assignment in line 44.

Comment: Ah I thought it was the reverse. Now I get this error: `ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer` line 44:29

Comment: And compare to `'y'` rather than `"y"`. Double quotes are for string literals. Chars are single-quoted.

Comment: is sale a pointer to an object or to a array of objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (sale->taxStatus[i] == 'y')
```

As @jweyrich and @AustinPhillips also pointed out that you need double equal sign ( == )  and chars are compared in single quotes.

single equal sign ( = ) is used to assign value.

e.g. `s = 5;`

double equal sign ( == ) is used to check equality of two or more than two values.

e.g. `if( s == d && d== e && e == f && f == b ) { };`

equal sign with exclamation mark ( != ) is used to check inequality of two or more than two values.

e.g. `if( s != d && d != e && e != f && f != b ) { };`

Comment: and i am rookie of c++ hahah :P

Comment: @JesseGood edited well, i belong to web development background and new  to `c` and `c++` :D

Comment: `x == y == z` does not check for equality among all the variables, it checks whether `z` is `(x == y)`, which is either a boolean or a zero-or-nonezero integer value (I don't remember). It doesn't work the way you say it does unless you have some crazy operator overloads in place. Same goes for `!=`.

Comment: Multiple comparisons "cannot" be chained like you did. You should use `&&` and/or `||`. E.g.: `if (s != d && s != e && s != f && s != b)`, unless of course your intention is really to successively compare the result of the previous comparison to the next variable/value.

Comment: ...and then probably `&& d != e && d != f && d != b && e != f && e != b && f != b`.

Comment: ahhh sorry forgot to use AND gate

Answer (score 0):

first of all, as already mentioned `if (sale->taxStatus[i] = "y")` is assign instead of compare!

but the main problem is: `sale` (function parameter) is an array (with size `sales`), but you access it (inside of `for` body) as a `Sale*`...

the correct access must be `sale[i]->taxStatus` because index `i` points inside of array `sale`, but not to `taxStatus`! (btw, if `sales > MAX_SALES` you'll get UB). then you need to use `strcmp` to compare against `"y"` literal...

Comment: 1) You're right about the array access; 2) He's storing a single char (`y`/`n`) for each position in `sale->taxStatus`, so it doesn't make sense to use `strcmp`. However, it's not clear what his intentions are. Having an array of `Sale` seems more appropriate IMO (thus removing the need for those arrays within the struct).

Comment: Better yet would be to split it in `typedef enum { not_taxed, taxed } tax_status_e;`, `struct sale_item { uint32_t quantity; float unitPrice; tax_status_e taxStatus; ... };` and `struct sale { sale_item *items; size_t amountOfItems; float summedPrice; ... };`. But this could be a little hard to grasp if he's learning.